# array formulas in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a simple question about array formulas in Excel that is probably easy to solve, but I'm stuck.

So let's say I have

- `1` in `A1` and `2` in `A2` and
- I want to find the sum of those two numbers, each multiplied by `3`

(i.e. `1*3 + 2*3 = 7`) using an array formula. I was trying `{=sum(A1*3:A2*3)}` but I got an error.

Comment: use sumproduct instead of sum.

Comment: Should the result not be `9`?

Comment: @ArshadHussain Using `sumproduct` in this way (with only one argument) is just a hack to avoid using `ctrl+shift+enter`. `{=sum(<expression>)}` is equivalent to `=sumproduct(<expression>)` (where `{...}` means entered with CSE).

Comment: I should really say that `sumproduct` is *often* equivalent, when the expression is simple. CSE is more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

First of all  1*3 + 2*3 = 9
and the correct formula is

```
=sum(A1*3,A2*3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well in this case you could: =sum(A1:A2)*3

Comment: +1 - why complicate things?, sum the values...then mutiply by your constant

Comment: @barryhoudini depends whether it's the technique understanding or this was the actual question. Merry Christmas :)

Comment: Hey Dave! Yes, I agree, I wasn't sure about that. I'd say that it isn't a very good example to choose if you're interested in the technique! Merry Christmas to you too, is it Xmas day where you are yet?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you don't have a range like in this example and that 3 is a constant.

Otherwise, this would work..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array formula:

```
    A    B
1   1
2   2
3        =SUM(A1:A2)*3 // = 9
```

N.B. use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to enter an array formula

Answer (score 0):

If you were to go the more complex route of array formulas then
    `=SUM(A1:A2*3)`

is cleaner and actually uses array techniques than array entering `=SUM(A1:A2)*3`
- your initial approch wasn't far off the approach I supplied.